# jQuery Slider in a browser extension not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, browser-extension, crossrider, jquery-slider

I am creating a browser extension in which i am using jQuery Range2DSlider plugin v1.0.5. Slider is working if installed in Chrome but is not working in firefox. The error message showing in firefox is

> Warning: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface
>   Node. Function-name: appAPI.message.addListener User callback

This error occurs when the slider runner is appending to slider box. The code in the Range2DSlider plugin to append the runner is as follows.

```
// create runners
var $runner;
for(i=0;i<_this.values.length;i++){
    if( !_this.$runners[i] ){
        _this.$runners.push($runner = $('<div class="xdsoft_range2dslider_runner xdsoft_range2dslider_runner'+i+'"></div>'));
        $runner.append($inrunner = $('<input type="button">'));
        $runner[0].ranges = [];
        $runner.addClass('xdsoft_range2dslider_'+_this.options.runnerClassSkin.xd(i));
        !function(i){
            $inrunner
                .on('focus',function(){
                    $('.xdsoft_range2dslider_active').removeClass('xdsoft_range2dslider_active');
                    $(this).parent().addClass('xdsoft_range2dslider_active');
                })
                .on('keydown',function( event ){
                    var relX = _this.values[i][0],
                        relY = _this.values[i][1],
                        ax = _this.options.allowAxisMove.xd(0,'both');
                    switch( event.which ){
                        case ARROWUP:
                            if( ax=='both'||ax=='y' ){
                                relY+=_this.options.stepOnKey.xd(1);
                            }
                        break;
                        case ARROWDOWN:
                            if( ax=='both'||ax=='y' ){
                                relY-=_this.options.stepOnKey.xd(1);
                            }
                        break;
                        case ARROWRIGHT:
                            if( ax=='both'||ax=='x' ){
                                relX+=_this.options.stepOnKey.xd(0);
                            }
                        break;
                        case ARROWLEFT:
                            if( ax=='both'||ax=='x' ){
                                relX-=_this.options.stepOnKey.xd(0);
                            }
                        break;
                        default: return true;
                    }
                    setValue(_this,i,relX,relY);
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
        }(i);
    }else{
        for(var t=0;t<_this.$runners[i][0].ranges.length;t++)
            _this.$runners[i][0].ranges[t].rect.remove();
        _this.$runners[i][0].ranges = [];
    }
}

// for second init remove extra sliders
for(i=_this.values.length;i<_this.$runners.length;i++){
    _this.$runners[i].remove();
}
_this.$runners.length = _this.values.length;

if( $.isArray(_this.options.showRanges)&&_this.options.showRanges.length&&_this.values.length>1 ){
    var range,$range ;
    for(i=0;i< _this.options.showRanges.length;i++){
        rangeBetween = _this.options.showRanges.xd(i);
        if( rangeBetween && $.isArray(rangeBetween) && rangeBetween.length && rangeBetween[0]!=rangeBetween[1] && _this.$runners[rangeBetween[0]] && _this.$runners[rangeBetween[1]] ){
            $range = $('<div class="xdsoft_range2dslider_range xdsoft_range2dslider_range'+i+'"></div>');                   
            _this.$runners[rangeBetween[0]][0].ranges.push({rect:$range,rb:rangeBetween});
            _this.$runners[rangeBetween[1]][0].ranges.push({rect:$range,rb:rangeBetween});
            _this.$sliderBox.append($range);
            $range.on('mousedown',function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    }
}


_this.$sliderBox
    .css({
        height:_this.options.height,
        width:_this.options.width
    })
    .append(_this.$runners);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The message indicates an error in the message listener callback function, specifically something to do with the appAPI.appendChild. Looking at the full extension.js code, I can see that you are using appendChild in several places. I suggest you start debugging around the appendChild method. [**Disclosure:** I am a Crossrider employee]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here _this.$runners is a jQuery object. append method accepts only DOM elements. changing the jQuery object to DOM element do the trick.

```
_this.$sliderBox
    .css({
        height:_this.options.height,
        width:_this.options.width
    })
    .append(_this.$runners[0]);
```

This code works now